# dataframe switch date to start week date start with Saturday

Tags: python, date, dataframe

I have a dataframe from 2019-06-01 to 2019-07-31 like this:

```
id date 
1   2019-06-02
2   2019-06-05
3   2019-06-08
4   2019-06-14
```

And I want it to be like:

```
id date        week_start_date
1   2019-06-02 2019-06-01
2   2019-06-05 2019-06-01
3   2019-06-08 2019-06-08
4   2019-06-14 2019-06-08
```

2019-06-01 is Saturday,so i want to set the week start-day as Saturday not Monday or Sunday. So is there a quick way to do it？

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer by jezrael
[Get week start date (Sunday) from a date column in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458525/get-week-start-date-sunday-from-a-date-column-in-python)

```
a = df['date'] - pd.offsets.Week(weekday=5)
m1 = df['date'] != (a + pd.offsets.Week())
df['week_start_date'] = df['date'].mask(m1, a)
```